# my carousel component doesn't auto slide in bootstrap 5.1.3, what could the issue?

Tags: carousel, auto

I've used data-bs-ride="carousel" in the html code but it still doesn't auto slide unless I start the sliding manually by clicking the next or previous button. I tried everything I thought could help but it still doesn't work,  below is line of html code containing the data-bs-ride code.